# Reading PSYCOPG2 connection credential from a file in python

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I have stored the redshift connection credentials in a file, test.txt in my local system. The file's contents are:

```
host='abcxyz.redshift.amazonaws.com',
user='def',
port=5439,
password='123456',
dbname='ijk'
```

I am calling the contents of the file in my python code as below:

```
import psycopg2
with open ('filepath\test.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()
conn = psycopg2.connect(data)
cur = conn.cursor()
```

However, it giving the following error:

psycopg2.ProgrammingError: invalid dsn: missing "=" after "data" in connection
 info string

Can anyone kindly let me know where exactly I am going wrong?

I tried to put the file contents inside quotes, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Has it something to do with the way the credentials are stored in the file? Does it need to be formatted in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by creating the file like:

```
abcxyz.redshift.amazonaws.com
def
5439
123456
ijk
```

and then saving it as test.txt
Then created an empty list and appended each row from the file to the list. Then used psycopg2 as:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host = cred_detail[0][0],
                        user = cred_detail[1][0],
                        port = cred_detail[2][0],
                        password = cred_detail[3][0],
                        dbname = cred_detail[4][0])
cur = conn.cursor()
```

This is not a good method to store and read credentials, but as of now, this solves my purpose. Kindly suggest any good method to hide/obscure credentials while connecting to AWS Redshift through Python.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration file should have following content and it will work. Please try.
I agree with you that your solution is not good, hence answering here so that could be useful for others.

```
host=yourhost.redshift.amazonaws.com
user=redshift-user
port=5439
password=redshift-password
dbname=redshift-database
```

Regarding your question in self answer,

> Kindly suggest any good method to hide/obscure credentials while connecting to AWS Redshift through Python.

There could be many ways to protect config files, and every way has some pros/cons. I would suggest a simple approach that I use(in Unix/Linux environment), make your property file under specific user and just keep read/write access to user only.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow native ~/.pgpass support from postgresql. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/libpq-pgpass.html for details.

Example ~/.pgpass file:

```
## hostname:port:database:username:password
## non-admin user
db.example.com:5432:db1:foo:apple
## admin user
db.example.com:5432:db1:postgres:pear
```

I've database setup via jupyter lab and use psycopg2 as postgres driver. I use following string and postgres picks up appropriate credentials for user: *foo* and database *db1* from ~/.pgpass file. I've not tried `psycopg2.connect` command but it should work with ~/.pgpass file.

```
postgresql://foo@db.example.com/db1
```

If SSL is required, then use following:

```
postgresql://foo@db.example.com/db1?sslmode=require
```